# Extract non-alphabet characters from paste() function in R

Tags: r, concatenation

The following variable:

```
x <- "^howdy"
```

Passed into the paste function like thus:

```
paste(x, "there", sep=".")
```

Returns the string `"^howdy.there"` as expected. How can you eliminate the caret from `howdy` so the string returns only `"howdy.there"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `gsub`:

```
paste(gsub("^","",x,fixed=TRUE),"there",sep=".")
```

Comment: `sub` could be even better cause it replace only first occurrence (`gsub` replace all).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a character vector and need to remove any non-alphanumeric characters, this slightly-more-complicated regular expression will be more efficient than explicitly specifying each character manually.

```
> gsub("[^[:alnum:]._]","",c("&hi_there%","^howdy.there"))
[1] "hi_there"    "howdy.there"
```

In regular expressions, the contents of `[]` are called a "character class" and each character inside the `[]` will be matched (or not matched if the first character is `^` as in the example above).  So we can use `gsub` to replace all characters that aren't alphanumeric, period, or underscore with the null string `""`.